# Formatting Numpy list

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Good Morning, im relatively new in python and I need some help with formatting. I have a Numpy list with the following format:

`[['SPY'], ['XLE'], ['XLF'], ['XLY'], ['GLD'], ['FXE']]`

But I would like to convert it to a list like this:

`['Games', 'Fin']`

Sorry for the dumb question and thank you for your help :)

Comment: How does the second list relate to the first? If you had to do it by hand, how would you get from the first list to the second? What have you tried yourself in Python? Please share your code and explain what exactly you're stuck on.

Comment: I don't get the question. How about `your_list = ['Games', 'Fin']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `flatten` method of the `np.array`.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['SPY'], ['XLE'], ['XLF'], ['XLY'], ['GLD'], ['FXE']])

print(a.flatten())
# ['SPY' 'XLE' 'XLF' 'XLY' 'GLD' 'FXE']
```

Source: [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)